# Плавный паралакс фона

Tags: javascript, анимация, прокрутка

Подскажите в каком направлении идти, обычно браузеры прокручивают страницу не плавно, а скачут

Дак вот мне надо чтоб при таких скачках фон (не контент или страница) прокручивался плавно, учитывая ещё и то, что некоторые браузеры уже имеют плавный скролл, это может вызвать некоторые проблемы

Answer (score 1):

А что вы уже попробовали ? просто непонятно в чем вообще проблема, кроме как написать код. делайте так например: onscroll - убиваем предыдущую анимацию, если не закончена, вычисляем новую позицию фона, расстояние до назначения, анимировано крутим фон (позицией css или еще как нравится). вот демку как-то делал похожую (тут transition используется, но можно и под animate  переделать) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QrWSb/